# Is my H bridge circuit correct?

Tags: h-bridge

[image]

Circuit operation of this circuit is when Switch is turn on as shown below , Q4 and Q3 turn . When the switch is turn downward , Q1 and Q2 turn on.

Does the circuit I created follow the circuit operation that I have come up?

Comment: R2 doesn't appear to be connected.

Comment: my bad. I think i left it out when I draw the circuit. Assuming it is connected to gate of Q1 and Q3 , is my circuit correct?

Comment: I don't think so.  You have all transistors as the same type, and you are driving each side of the H with the same control signal.  Looks to me like you'd have a short straight from 12V to ground either through Q1+Q3 or Q4+Q2.  Flipping the switch would then kill whichever pair didn't die when you connected the battery.

Comment: may i know how do I fix it? I need to design a h bridge using only N Mosfet

Comment: Step 1: Go study H bridges in general.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. You have all transistors marked as the same type, and you are driving each side of the H with the same control signal.

Looks to me like you'd have a short straight from 12V to ground either through Q1+Q3 or Q4+Q2.

Flipping the switch would then kill whichever pair didn't die when you connected the battery.

Conceptually, you have one big problem.  You are driving the transistor pairs incorrectly.  You should be driving Q1+Q2 with the same control signal and Q3+Q4 together.

Practically, you have another problem.  From what I've read here on EE stackexchange, you will have problems switching the N-Type FETs on the high side.  You need a higher voltage on the gate than on the source to make the FET switch.

You need to do more reading on FETs and H-Bridges, then try again.

There are lots of questions about H-Bridges on this site, so you might want to start by doing a search and seeing what comes up.